# Python: stopping gravity

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to create realistic gravity using tkinter in python. The gravity works, but the ball I am animating does not stop. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

xv=0
yv=0
x=0
y=0
def move(event=None):
    global xv,yv, direction

    if event.char == 'w':
        yv-=15
    elif event.char == 'a':
        xv-=1
    elif event.char == 'd':
        xv+=1
    elif event.char == 's':
        yv+=1


m = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(m)
canvas.pack(expand=2, fill='both')
oval_id = canvas.create_oval(0,0,10,10,fill='red')

canvas.bind_all('<w>', move) 
canvas.bind_all('<a>', move) 
canvas.bind_all('<d>', move) 
canvas.bind_all('<s>', move)  

while 0==0:   
    yv*=0.9
    xv*=0.9
    x+=xv
    y+=yv
    yv+=1
    if y > 170:
        yv=0
    time.sleep(0.05)
    canvas.move(oval_id,xv,yv)
    canvas.update()
```

The ball does stop, but when you press w to jump, it sinks down and is lower on the screen. can I get it to go back up to 170px without using too much code?

Comment: From the names of your variables (`xv`, `yv`), you're working with velocities, not accelerations. For a reasonably serious gravity model to work, you should only be working with accelerations.

Comment: That isn't what i'm working with. The problem isn't the acceleration, it'sthe fact that the gravity stop gets lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute coordinates and constant downward acceleration:

```
yv = 0
xv = 1
while True:
    yv += .5 # .5 is the acceleration
    x+=xv
    y+=yv
    if y > 170: # check that didn't move past the floor
        y=170        # reset to the floor
        yv = -yv*.9  # reverse velocity and lose some energy from the bounce
    time.sleep(0.05)
    canvas.coords(oval_id,x,y,x+10,y+10) # use absolute coordinates
    canvas.update()
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfect. I did modify it a bit, because the finished code will be for a platformer game, but now it works just like I wanted it to!